# C#: How to override/replace a variables inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding, multiple-inheritance

This is a strange question, I understand that you can't override a variable in C#. Maybe this won't work. I am trying to take a variable that's type is a class and override it with child of that class.

To put it into context, I have a `Character` class. It has a variable `attackSystem` of type `AttackSystem`. I have a `NPC` class that inherits from `Character` and I am trying to override `attackSystem` to be of type `NPCAttackSystem` which inherits from `AttackSystem`.

Is this doable? Or, am I complexifying things too much? Should I not "override" the variable and instead just say in the constructor of `NPC` that `attackSystem = new NPCAttackSystem()`

**(A)** What I'm doing (doesn't work):

```
public class Character
{
    public AttackSystem attackSystem = new AttackSystem();
}

public class NPC : Character
{
    public NPCAttackSystem attackSystem = new NPCAttackSystem();;
}

public class AttackSystem {}
public class NPCAttackSystem: AttackSystem {}
```

**(B)** What I should do?

```
public class Character
{
    public AttackSystem attackSystem = new AttackSystem();;
}

public class NPC : Character
{
    NPC()
    {
        attackSystem = new NPCAttackSystem();
    }
}

public class AttackSystem {}
public class NPCAttackSystem: AttackSystem {}
```

I frequently answer my own questions, in my own question. Just wondering If I can do it the way I want (A) or if I should do it the other way (B). Will the other way (B) work? Will I be able to access the members of `NPCAttackSystem` that way?

Sorry for all the questions, a simple A.) or B.) will do.

Thanks for help, I love asking questions on here.

Comment: `public class Character<T> where T: AttackSystem`.

Comment: You can do it inside a method.  Right now attachSystem is defined in the base class so you cannot have another property attachsystem in the inherited class unless you use override.

Comment: You mean like `public class Character<AttackSystem>`? If so, can I add multiple system like this `public class Character<AttackSystem, MotorSystem, InventorySystem>`? Most of my base classes systems will have child classes like this. `public class NPC<NPCAttackSystem, NPCMotorSystem, NPCInventory>: Character`.

Comment: `public virtual AttackSystem AttackSystem { get; set; }= new AttackSystem(); ` and  `public override AttackSystem AttackSystem { get; set; }= new NPCAttackSystem();` i dont see what the problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an approach like below. The main benefit of this approach is that the compiler knows that `npc.AttackSystem` is of type `NPCAttackSystem` (or at least of a type that can be cast safely to NPCAttackSystem)).

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public abstract class Character<T> where T: AttackSystem, new()
    {
        public T AttackSystem { get; } = new T();
    }

    public class PC: Character<AttackSystem>
    {
    }
    
    public class NPC : Character<NPCAttackSystem>
    {
    }

    public class AttackSystem {}
    public class NPCAttackSystem: AttackSystem {}
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        var normal = new PC();
        var npc = new NPC();
        
        Console.WriteLine(normal.AttackSystem.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine(npc.AttackSystem.GetType());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
public class Character
{
    public Character() : this(new AttackSystem())
    {
    }

    protected Character(AttackSystem attackSystem)
    {
        AttackSystem = attackSystem;
    }

    public AttackSystem AttackSystem { get; }
}

public class NpcCharacter : Character
{
    public NpcCharacter() : base(new NpcAttackSystem())
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: This is really clean. How do i access `AttackSystem` without accessing the classes definition if it is of the same name?